# Flipcard made using Bootstrap 4 not quite working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a flipcard, where the card itself remains at a fixed size when flipped.
However, when the first defined (front) face of the card is larger/longer than the second side, the card does not get the correct size.

I have been playing around with the code, but can't seem to find a good solution. What am I doing wrong?

[Link to example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/jagoop/pen/wvvYXjR)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="flip">
        <div class="card shadow my-2 mx-0 p-0" id="card-1">
            <div class="face front"> 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <h4><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Chart 1.0</span></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark border-0 card-1-button">TURN</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="face back"> 
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="float-left">
                            <h4><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">Chart 1.0</span></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="float-right">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark border-0 card-1-button">TURN</a>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <table class="table table-sm table-striped my-5">
                                <thead class="thead-dark">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">Label</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Value</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>A</td>
                                        <td>14</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>B</td>
                                        <td>32</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>C</td>
                                        <td>17</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

PS
The codepen example is only working in chrome atm, transparency is wrong in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

resize myChart width and height to let it fit in the card, or grow the card width and height

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your solution would be better with some code showing *how* OP would implement it. Please [edit your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58862482/edit) to include it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, I have been unable to find a working solution that grows the card width and height, while not breaking general responsiveness. Can you elaborate or give an example on how to do this?